# vue (v2) transition-group does not work with *-move class

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the example below,
when inserting an item from last to first, the transition works well,
however, when inserting an item from first to last, the transition dose not work.

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/dzg-melody/pen/BayyJNy?editors=0010)
```

Comment: the example link: https://codepen.io/dzg-melody/pen/BayyJNy?editors=0010

Comment: Whats the point of changing keys?